# Camera for iOS10 and older in Swift 3/4

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, camera, photo

I'm trying to implement a camera in my app. It seems to work well on iOS 11 but not on the previous version.

XCode tells me that this part (the function `photoOutput()`) is not good for iOS 10 and older version.

```
extension UploadViewController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

    @available(iOS 11.0, *)
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
            image = UIImage(data: imageData)

            let photoSecondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "uploadSecondVC") as! UploadSecondViewController
            photoSecondVC.imageData = image!
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(photoSecondVC, animated: false)
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
   }

}
```

And this is the action for taking a picture:

```
@IBAction func takePhotoAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
}
```

I don't know how I could translate this function for the previous versions of iOS.

I found this one:

```
func photoOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhoto previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?)
```

But there a a lot of parameters and it's not working well, I'm not sure it's the good one :/

Here is what I tried:

```
@IBAction func takePhotoAction(_ sender: Any) {
  let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
  let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
  let previewFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
                       kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160,
                       kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160]
  settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat
  photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
   }

func photoOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhoto previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {

  if let error = error {
     print("error occure : \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }

  if  let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer,
     let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer,
     let dataImage =  AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer:  sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {


     print(UIImage(data: dataImage)?.size as Any)

     let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: dataImage as CFData)
     let cgImageRef: CGImage! = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent)

     var orientation = UIImageOrientation(rawValue: 0)

     if isFront {
        orientation = UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored

     } else {
        orientation = UIImageOrientation.right
     }

     let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: orientation!)
     // var flippedImage = UIImage(CGImage: picture.CGImage!, scale: picture.scale, orientation: .leftMirrored)
     let timage = crop(image, withWidth: 100, andHeight: 100)

     let photoSecondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "uploadSecondVC") as! UploadSecondViewController
     photoSecondVC.imageData = timage!
     photoSecondVC.isFront = isFront
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(photoSecondVC, animated: false)

  } else {
     print("some error here")
  }
   }
```

There is a huge delay when I take the picture (4 or 5 seconds). Do you know why?

Comment: "But there a a lot of parameters and it's not working well, I'm not sure it's the good one :/" What about a lot of parameters? What wrong with that? Define "not working well".

Comment: @available(iOS 11.0, *) indicates it is made for iOS 11 Only.You need to implement func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, 
 didFinishProcessingPhoto photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, 
             previewPhoto previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, 
         resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, 
          bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, 
                    error: Error?) for iOS 10.

Comment: It is a delegate method so you can fallback based on iOS Version.

Comment: I tried to use that function but there is a delay when I take the picture (maybe 5 seconds ...)